# Bootstrap buttons get "stuck" down on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, dom, mobile, twitter-bootstrap

Whenever I click a button with my mobile device (android) on a twitter boostrap button but button gets odd styling like the mouse is still over and doesn't release until I click another element. This is not the active class being applied to an element. 
[image: This is what the button looks like before clicking]

[image: This is what the button looks like after clicking notice the shading and background]

It's subtle but very annoying, especially when I try to apply styles to the button they dont show up until i click on a different element.

Try going to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons on a mobile device and click a button you'll see what i mean

I tried triggering all sorts of events with jquery but nothing worked, this is a snippet i have at the END of my javascript

```
$(document).on('tapclick', '.btn', function() {
          $(this).blur(); 
          $(this).trigger('mouseup'); 


        });
```

and tried overriding css stylings on hover

```
.btn a:hover,.btn a:link,.btn a:visited,.btn a:active{
text-decoration: none !important;
cursor: default !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
background-image: none !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adding a class to the button on the touchend event and then overriding the default bootstrap background position.

javascript:

```
$("button").on("touchstart", function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass("mobileHoverFix");
});
$("button").on("touchend", function(){ 
    $(this).addClass("mobileHoverFix");
});
```

css:

```
.mobileHoverFix:hover,
.mobileHoverFix.hover{
    background-position: 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This has been bugging me for a while

Answer (score 9):

If you are just developing for mobile then you could simply override the hover css altogether, for example:

```css
.btn:hover {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: This should be the approved answer. It's clean and only uses css. You will probably have to tweak the inherit statements to match the exact style of the non-hover state