# touch the screen programmatically phonegap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, button

Whenever I click on a bootstrap button in the app, its gets stuck in a active or hover state, unless I click somewhere on the screen. So I'm thinking thats a easy solution

1) detect when someone clicks a bootstrap button

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '.btn', function(){ 
    console.log("button touch"); 
});
```

2) **How can I somehow click somewhere on the screen so button is unstuck?** (touchend event is occuring on bootstrap buttons)

```
$(document).on('touchend', '.btn', function(){ 
    console.log("button touch end");
    // ?????????????
});
```

My bootstrap buttons get stuck on phonegap app and I've tried all these answers

1) doesn't fix problem at all
[Bootstrap buttons get "stuck" down on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305914/bootstrap-buttons-get-stuck-down-on-mobile-devices)

2) I don't wanna change background
[bootstrap 3 button hover/focus state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668104/bootstrap-3-button-hover-focus-state)

Comment: You are on the right path. Basically, if you want to avoid this behavior you have to not use `:hover` pseudo-classes and instead write your own handlers for `mouseenter mouseleave touchstart touchend` (etc) that toggle a class or attribute on the element in question. Note that `touchend` might not occur on the targeted element and there may be multiple touch points at any given time. For more information, I'd recommend [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22444532/1028949) to a similar question.

Comment: oh ok so do you recommend digging into boostrap js and customizing these functions?

Comment: btw touch end event is occuring on bootstrap buttons

Answer (score 0):

You should probably find out the underlaying issue. But to answer your question you can use [tigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/). Taking the example from the links:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
    alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
    $( "#target" ).click();
});
```

Comment: .click() doesn't work. I have a another button hidden in the navbar, I tried clicking that button on the ontouchend function programatically but it doesn't have the same affect as physically touching the button