# How to remove focus from Bootstrap buttons in Toggable Tab panes

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap buttons in Toggable Tab panes and what I find is that on iPhones, iPads, and on Samsung Galaxy S4 after a 'next' button is clicked the button colour changes and the pane changes but the button does not revert back to default colour it stays in hover/active colour. I've tried various tricks mentioned on the web including blur() but so far have not solved it.

```
$('.btn-primary').focus(function() {
        this.blur();
});

window.onblur = function () {
  document.activeElement.blur();
};
```

The code is at: https://jsfiddle.net/qb3uckc8/2/

As well as setting blur() must I also change the css in jquery, or is there a css solution?

It works fine on PCs, just on mobiles it's not.

Comment: Probably it stays in **active** state, so the CSS don't go back to normal. One solution would be erase the **:active** CSS and let only the CSS on **:hover**. Have you tried that?

Comment: I've tried over riding the active state, you see that in the jsfiddle

.btn-primary:active,.btn-primary.active,.btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary.focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #999999!important;
    border-color: #333399!important;
}

Comment: It seems like the button keeps the hover state. If you set only :active CSS it works https://jsfiddle.net/qb3uckc8/3/

Comment: Thank you matheusr. Your changes didn't work in my test file until I changed bootstrap from v3.3.1 that I had reference to v3.3.6 as referenced in the fiddles, then it worked.

Comment: If I didn't want to change the bootstrap version (I'm worried what style changes this might cause), might this shim corrct the issue: https://github.com/twbs/mq4-hover-shim

Comment: With Bootstrap 3.3.1, toggleClass works after the first click but not after the second click: 
 $(".btn-primary").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
 });

Comment: I think it's ok to upgrade to Bootstrap v3.3.6, it's just a minor update, shouldn't change any styles, just bugfixes

Comment: I might try the Bootstrap update. I find that this works:  $(".btn-primary").click(function(){  
   $(this).removeClass("active");
  $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active"); }); BUT I lose the hover colour.

Comment: This is the best fix I could find to work without updating Bootstrap, seems to be a 'sticky hover bug on mobiles' (certainly iOS on iPad and iPhone  and on Samsung browsers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305914/bootstrap-buttons-get-stuck-down-on-mobile-devices